# Show data from database (python) in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show the RandomId which is saved in database in my HTML, but I am not sure how to do it. Anyone know how to do it?

```
Here is my html
</script> 
<button onclick="myFunction()"><input type="submit" value="Place Order"></button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
             alert("Order has been placed in the kitchen \n Your order ID is 
             {{% random_id %}}")    
    }
</script>

here is my views.py

RandomId = request.POST.get("RandomId")
RandomId = get_random_string(length=5) #get random string id 
#RandomId = request.POST.get("RandomId")
customerOrder = CustomerOrder(Table_Num=Table_Num , Food=Food, Quantity=Quantity, Message=Message, RandomId=RandomId) #get data into the CustomerOrder db
customerOrder.save() #save data into db

random_id = CustomerOrder.objects.all()

#order_summary = CustomerOrder.objects.filter(Table_Num = request.Table_Num)
#order_summary = CustomerOrder.objects.filter(Table_Num = 15)

return render(request, 'restaurants/customer_page.html', {'random_id': random_id}) #return customer page
```

Answer (score 0):

here we go

in your html

```py
{% for id in random_id %}
    {{ id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please shorten your code to the relevant parts. And split up your code into different sections to make it easier to read. Like

template:

```html
<p>Some html here </p>
```

view:

```py
def my_view(request):
   # things that happen here
```

Additionally your code defines `RandomId` twice and you seem to be inserting uncleaned data into your database. Use forms, use [form.is_valid()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation), provide your model information, and double check when to use `{{ something_here }}` and `{% something_else_here %}`. Hint: `{{ variable }}`, and `{% if variable == 'hello world' %}`.